# Multivariable Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Working currently on multivariable integrals, I got stucked. Let $R=[0,1]^3 \subset \Bbb R^3$. Suppose $f:R \to \Bbb R$ is defined by
$$\begin{align*}
    \displaystyle f(x,y,z)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}1&\text{if }x+y+z \leq 1\\0&\text{else}\end{array}\right.\hspace{.25in}
\end{align*}$$
I wanna now show that $f$ is integrable (in the sense of Riemann) but I don't know how to do it. I guess I should show that the upper and the lower integral are the same, but I don't know how to start..

Answer (score 1):

Break up the domain into tiny cubes.  Except for points along the plane $x+y+z=1$, the upper and lower contribution will be the same, while the total contribution of cubes containing points on the plane will go to $0$ as cubes shrink..